# Dictionary<T, Func>: how to use T as Func's generic type?

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, func

I didn't know how to express it clearly.

I have this interface:

```
interface IConverter
{
    Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> ConversionMethods { get; }
}
```

Basically, it defines a contract saying that a class implementing it should provide conversion methods for all the custom types it uses (be them enums or anything).

Is it possible to replace `object` in `Func`'s generic types with its corresponding dictionary key's type (so it is impossible to have two unmatching types)?

*I think it's not possible, but the alternatives are a bit annoying (using `dynamic` or `object`, creating a specialized dictionary...).*

---

edit 1: Imaginary exemple of use

```
interface IConverter
{
    Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> GetConversionMethods();
}

enum A
{
    AA,AB,AC
}

enum B
{
    BA, BB, BC
}

class blah : IConverter
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> GetConversionMethods()
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>
        {
            {
                typeof(A),
                (s) =>
                    {
                        // here, I could return whatever I want because the 'Func' returns 'object'
                        return s == "AA" ? A.AA : s == "AB" ? A.AB : A.AC;
                    }
            },
            {
                typeof(B),
                (s) =>
                    {
                        // same
                        return s == "BA" ? B.BA : s == "BB" ? B.BB : B.BC;
                    }
            }
        };
        return d;
    }

    void blahah()
    {
        // and here, I also get an `object`, where I would like to have a A
        GetConversionMethods()[typeof(A)]("123");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an exemplary code snippet of how you intend to access such an imaginary dictionary, if it were possible?

Comment: @Kilazur, _"Is it possible to replace Type in Func's generic types"_... do you mean to replace `object`?

Comment: it's not possible at compile time.

Comment: The example posted so far shows how you would fill the dictionary. But in that code, having the functions typed using `object` or `dynamic` would not yet be "annoying", as you say, would it? I suppose the annoying part would follow once you attempt to read from the dictionary, when you have to cast - can you show an example of that usage, as well, please? Concretely, I wonder whether you will know the type being retrieved at compiletime (in which case you might not need a dictionary), or whether it is only known at runtime (in which case I cannot imagine how you use the results type-safely).

Comment: This is, where the generic pattern ends. Simply, it's not possible.

Comment: Added an example. It's not pretty, but it shows the principle.

Comment: This is related to something I've tried before. You can get close, but not by this route. Basically, it is possible to use generics to enforce the requirements you're after, but not by just using the existing types; you'll need a few custom types. I'll see if I can distil an example to something that will work as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets a bit complex, but it works.

First, you'll need to encapsulate the conversion `Func`s inside classes, so that you can handle them more easily and without exposing all their differing type arguments. Then you'll need to define interfaces or base classes to hide the various generic arguments from places they'll cause problems, and allow you to put different converters in the same collection. Then, you'll need ways for the various converters to signal what types they work with without using those type arguments directly. Then you just need to wrap it all in a class with a method that'll find you the right converter on demand.

I'll walk you through it.

First, this base class will be our way to handle a converter without worrying about its generic type arguments, but still know what types it work with.

```
public abstract class OneWayTypeConverterBase : IConvertFromType, IConvertToType
{
    public abstract Type AcceptsType { get; }
    public abstract Type ReturnsType { get; }
}
```

Now we inherit from that base class. This is the class that does the actual work of converting; you can instantiate it with a lambda that does whatever conversion operation you need. Notice that it implements the properties we defined above.

```
public class OneWayTypeConverter<TSource, TTarget> : OneWayTypeConverterBase
{
    public OneWayTypeConverter(Func<TSource, TTarget> conversionMethod)
    {
        _conversionMethod = conversionMethod;
    }

    public override Type AcceptsType => typeof(TSource);
    public override Type ReturnsType => typeof(TTarget);

    private readonly Func<TSource, TTarget> _conversionMethod;

    public TTarget Convert(TSource sourceObject)
    {
        return _conversionMethod(sourceObject);
    }
}
```

Now we need a single place to hold all of this, so that consuming code has an entry point. For simplicity, I had it take in a flat collection of converters, and then file them all into nested dictionaries so that it can do the lookups later without having to call `typeof` all the time.

```
public class TypeConverter
{
    public TypeConverter(IEnumerable<OneWayTypeConverterBase> converters)
    {
        _converters = converters
            .GroupBy(x => x.AcceptsType)
            .ToDictionary(
                kSource => kSource.Key,
                vSource => vSource
                    .ToDictionary(kTarget => kTarget.ReturnsType, vTarget => vTarget));
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, OneWayTypeConverterBase>> _converters;

    public TTarget ConvertType<TSource, TTarget>(TSource sourceObject)
    {
        Dictionary<Type, OneWayTypeConverterBase> baseConverters;

        if (_converters.TryGetValue(sourceObject.GetType(), out baseConverters))
        {
            OneWayTypeConverterBase baseConverter;

            if (baseConverters.TryGetValue(typeof(TTarget), out baseConverter))
            {
                OneWayTypeConverter<TSource, TTarget> converter = baseConverter as OneWayTypeConverter<TSource, TTarget>;

                if (converter != null)
                {
                    return converter.Convert(sourceObject);
                }
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("No converter found for that target type");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No converters found for that source type");
        }
    }
}
```

So now, you can set it up like this:

```
var converter = new TypeConverter(new List<OneWayTypeConverterBase>
{
    new OneWayTypeConverter<int, string>(x => $"The number was {x}"),
    new OneWayTypeConverter<int, bool>(x => x != 0),
    new OneWayTypeConverter<bool, string>(x => $"The bool was {x}")
});
```

and then whenever you need it, you can just use it like this:

```
var result = converter.ConvertType<int, string>(4);
```

Comment: That actually looks almost perfect. The only downside is the IEnumerable that allows multiple methods for a single type, but that's manageable. I'll test it later, but it looks very good.

Comment: You could easily check for multiple converters for the same type when you're converting to dictionary, and throw an exception, or you could provide a method for adding converters one at a time and check for existing converters of that type before adding the new one. The latter would be my preferred method, but the constructor method is still nice to have so that you can set up a `TypeConverter` quickly, so I'd probably implement both. If you'd like, I could add that to my code example?

Comment: Ah, it doesn't work for me actually; what I want seems impossible, because at some point I will need to use variable as generic types, which is not supported by the language. Your example would work if I could remove the generic types from `ConvertType`

Comment: If you don't have a type argument on `ConvertType`, there's no way the compiler can tell what type it'll return - you'd be stuck returning `object` or `dynamic`, or perhaps some `IConvertible` base interface, which is equally vague. You can alter that method so that it takes instances of `Type` instead of those type arguments and is properly constrained by them, but without a type argument there will always come a point where you have to fall back to `object` or something.

Comment: If you can't get to a type argument, your other options are to use reflection to use the `Type` instances you have to construct generic type arguments, or to use instances of each of the types (or use `Activator.CreateInstance()` to get hold of instances) and then let type inference get you there.

Comment: Very useful and well explained.

Comment: What is `IConvertFromType` and `IConvertToType` on your base class?

Answer (score 2):

It depends in how far you can change the signatures, but at the least the interface can enforce using a generic type. How the converters are added strongly typed is then the responsibility of the implementer and never of the caller.

The implementation itself can use any construction to provide the converter. Event if...else, but to use a dictionary under the hood, a dictionary of the type `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` can be used, where the converters can be added strongly typed. The example below uses a helper `set<T>` function to ensure the dictionary is set in the expected manner.

```
interface IConverter
{
    Func<string,T> GetConverter<T>(); //the method returned is always strongly typed, so the caller is never responsible for type checking
}

enum A{AA,AB,AC}    
enum B{BA, BB, BC}

class blah : IConverter
{
    public Func<string,T> GetConverter<T>()
    {
        if(methods.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var fn)) //side note, out var fn will not work in older visual studio versions. In that case declare fn before this line
            return (Func<string,T>)fn; //the set<T> method ensures that this conversion is safe
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    public blah()
    {
        set<A>(s => s == "AA" ? A.AA : s == "AB" ? A.AB : A.AC); //copied from the example. Enum.Parse could perhaps be used instead
        set<B>(s => s == "BA" ? B.BA : s == "BB" ? B.BB : B.BC);
    }

    Dictionary<Type, Delegate> methods= new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>(); // Delegate can be used as a type to handle all lambda's. It's the implementers responsibility to handle with care. Something like the set<T> helper method is recommended

    void set<T>(Func<string,T> fn) //helper method to assign the strongly typed methods to the specific type
    {
        methods[typeof(T)] = fn;
    }
}

static void blahah()
{
    new blah().GetConverter<A>()("123");
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but the interface has to have a way to return all the conversion methods, so I can use them elsewhere without having to know the types beforehand.

Comment: @Kilazur it's not possible unless you use dynamic or object or maybe a common interface for all types

Comment: @Zbigniew that was my guess as well

Comment: You could have the interface/class also return all Delegate (dictionary values) in a seperate method. Personally I would keep the direct calls to a conversion method strongly typed. But if the goal is more extended extra wrappers around the converters themselves would probably be preferrable.