# Using generic PubSubEvents for Prism Eventaggregator WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am trying to wrap access to [Events](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/PubSubEvent.cs) from the [EventAggregator](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/EventAggregator.cs) of Prism for re-usability

Here's a sample code

```
protected void Subscription<T1,T2>(Action<T2> OnSubcribe) where T1:CachedEvent<T2>
{
    T1 @event  = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<T1>();
    event.Subcribe(OnSubcribe,true);
    //Some Codes other codes
}
```

I have placed a constraint on `T1` , `CachedEvent`, which is a non-abstract derived class of `PubSubEvent<TPayload>`

But I am still getting an error

> 'T1' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter....

Assuming that this is not really valid in C#, are there any other alternatives?

**UPDATE**:

Here's what I did so far
I have made`@event` a parameter

```
protected void Subscription<T1,T2>(T1 @event, Action<T2> OnSubcribe) where T1:CachedEvent<T2>
{
    @event.Subcribe(OnSubcribe,true);
    //Some Codes other codes
}
```

My Application works, but I'm still not free from the boiler point of creating the `@event`, calling the `GetEvent` manually, each time i call `Subscription`

example:

```
Subcription(eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEventBasedOnCachedEvent>(),AMethodDoneOnSubcribe);
```

Comment: I dabbled with a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072996/dictionaryt-func-how-to-use-t-as-funcs-generic-type) and concluded that it was not worth the headaches; go with a parent class.

Comment: I've seen your query just now. going for parent class with generics won't do for my app because of how it was built. furthermore, eventaggregators.Getevent will only be accessed through generic inputs of types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've been missing all this time was the **`new()`** constraint for generic type `T1`.

Apparently `GetEvent<T>` of Prism [IEventAggregator](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Events/EventAggregator.cs) requires that `T` must have a parameterless constructor.

```
protected void Subscription<T1,T2>(Action<T2> OnSubcribe) where T1:CachedEvent<T2>,new()
{
    T1 @event  = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<T1>();
    event.Subcribe(OnSubcribe,true);
    //Some Codes other codes
}
```